# What's the meaning of "an die" in this sentence?

Tags: preposition, pronoun

Could you please tell me, what role or meaning "an die" serves in this sentence?

> Facebook sieht zwar inzwischen vor, dass man sein Profil nicht bloß deaktivieren, sondern für immer löschen kann. Die Prozedur dauert aber insgesamt "an die" drei Monate.

I googled "an etwas dauern" and "insgesamt an etwas" but found no such constructions.

Comment: Check out definition III - https://www.dwds.de/wb/an

Comment: @cruthers please write answers as answers, not comments

Comment: @cruthers Got it! Many thanks! But now I kinda feel stupid that it was that easy to find the answer, should I delete the question?

Comment: It's easy to overlook. Write a short answer and self-accept it